# NullReference error on foreach used to create radiobuttons on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am teaching myself asp .net mvc3. I have a "add property" form which allows user to upload property details to the website. I have been struggling with this error for a long time now.

For simplification, lets consider that I have two tables in my database.

CustomerTypes: The database has 1 Owner, 2 Broker, 3 Commercial etc
Property: This is the table that gets populated by the form.

I use CustomerTypes (and other such tables) to create radio buttons. The user fills the form and selects a choice for "customer type". However, I get an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on submit. This is is because "null" is
set for Model.CustomerTypes. However, Model.CustomerTypes is only used to create radio buttons. I am not sure what is wrong. The code is below:

View:

```
@model Website.ViewModels.AddPropertyViewModel

<fieldset>
    <legend>Property</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property.CustomerType)
        @foreach (var item in Model.CustomerTypes)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Property.CustomerType, Convert.ToInt32(item.Value)) @item.Text
        }
    </div>

    ...
```

AddPropertyViewModel:

```
namespace Website.ViewModels
{
    public class AddPropertyViewModel
    {
        public Property Property { get; set; }
        ...

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerTypes { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddProperty()
    {
        AddPropertyViewModel viewModel = new AddPropertyViewModel
        {
                ...
            CustomerTypes = websiterepository.GetCustomerTypeSelectList(),
                ...
        };
        return View(viewModel);
```

GetCustomerTypeSelectList functions is:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCustomerTypeSelectList()
{
    var customerTypes = from p in db.CustomerType
                            orderby p.CustomerTypeDescription
                            select new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = p.CustomerTypeDescription,
                                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.CustomerTypeId)
                            };
    return customerTypes;
}
```

The value in POST is set for Property_CustomerType correctly based on the selection

--- Added further info ---
I start the form as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProperty", "Property", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
...
}
```

The controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProperty(AddPropertyViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // 
        if (viewModel.File1.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(viewModel.File1.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
            viewModel.File1.SaveAs(path);
        }

        var property = viewModel.Property;
        websiterepository.Add(property);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of error:
[image]

I have tried submitting the form commenting these radio buttons and it works.

Comment: It does not look like there is any chance for `Model.CustomerTypes` to be `null`. Are you triple sure that's the case?

Comment: Can we see the action that you're posting to please.

Comment: Added the requesting information guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `CustomerTypes` isn't populated when your render the view after posting to the server.

If we look at the flow of actions being performed we see that

1. You populate the `CustomerTypes` collection before rendering the
   inital page
2. You post your data back to the server but do not
   preserve the `CustomerTypes` collection (Because there's no need to)
3. You render the view again but this time without populating
   `CustomerTypes`.
4. Kaboom!

Populating the CustomerTypes property before you return the view for the second time should fix your problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProperty(AddPropertyViewModel viewModel)
{
 [...]

 viewModel.CustomerTypes = websiterepository.GetCustomerTypeSelectList();

 return View(viewModel);
}
```